# Microsoft ReportViewer System.IOException with Subreports, RV Looking in Wrong Directory

Tags: c#, reportviewer, subreport, report-viewer2010

I have several reports in a project I am working on that were created by someone else who no long works for the company. The reports all work fine, most have multiple subreports that work fine as well. One particular report that I have been working on also has multiple subreports but they are not working.

The subreports show up and display just as they should, so from the outside they look like everything is working just fine. However, when I display the report I get about 5 sets of System.IOExceptions for each subreport. The exceptions state that the subreport files cannot be found and for some reason it is looking for the subreport files in the 'c:/' directory. I cannot figure out why this happening and why it is happening for only this one report.

I know that the subreport files should be in the same directory as the report they are being used with and they are in fact there. I've looked through the source in each report and subreport file and nothing in them indicates any differences between the reports that don't throw the exceptions and the ones that do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a file access rights issue. I had the project saved under the root directory but moving it to the default location ("Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/") fixed the issue.